# is there an ability to just view my unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

i often want to make sure i check off questions that have been answered. but there is no way to filter your own view of questions by unanswered.

you get sorting (newest, votes, views, etc) but no filtering on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a few things suggested on [the Search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

In the case of your own questions that have no answers, you'd want to note these two:

```
user:1234  posts from a specific user
answers:1  questions that have a minimum number of answers
```

And then build up the search string subbing in your info.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:4653+answers:0

Comment: answers:0 doesn't follow the documentation as it returns questions with *exactly* 0 answers (instead of at least 0 answers). But all the better, as that's more useful, and enables what OP asked for.

Comment: Have no idea how that worked really.

Comment: this works pretty well, I saw a few questions which were not answered at all, so I can at least see the questions.