# How do you list all your unanswered questions?

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions

How I can display the list of questions that I've asked but haven't yet been answered?

Thanks a bunch all.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16530/is-there-an-ability-to-just-view-my-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using advanced search

> user:me answers:0

Comment: let me give it a try :)