# view my unanswered questions

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

How do I see my open, or unanswered, questions?  It [seems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100893/177328) that this is a lacking feature, and that [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16530/177328) have asked for similar functionality.

I would like to review my unanswered, or questions where I didn't accept an answer, as maybe I later found the answer, or to ask differently.  I'm also just curious, as I generally get comments, if not answers, in real time.  Although I know of at least one question which I never expect to get answered, but it would still be interesting to have such a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to list all your unanswered questions, you can still do so with several queries:

- [user:me answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+answers%3A0&submit=search)
- [user:me hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0&submit=search)

If you want to find *someone else's* unanswered questions, replace the "me" in "user:me" with the user ID of whoever's questions you wish to search.

Comment: This definitely works, but it should definitely be easier to get at since SO shows the % accepted for a user in many places. Perhaps the % accepted should be clickable?